# iOS: Simple NSMutableArray Call

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I need to call `removeObject` in one of my methods, but I can't figure out how to do this correctly. I'm very new to Objective-C, and am still learning the basics. I have an app that behaves somewhat like a photo gallery, and displays UIImageViews. I'm implementing the option to have the user delete photos from their gallery. To accomplish this, I decided to place an invisible button over each picture. When the user hits an "Edit" button, the hidden delete button over each picture becomes active (I'm using the same IBOutlet over each of the hidden buttons, for simplicity). When the user taps the button over the picture, an alert view appears asking if they really want to delete it. If they click yes, deleteAlertView comes into play:

```
- (void)deleteAlertView:(UIAlertView *)deleteButtonPressed
       didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != [deleteButtonPressed cancelButtonIndex]) {
        [array removeObject:@"%@", deleteButtonPressed];
    }
```

The issue here is `[array removeObject:@"%@", deleteButtonPressed];`, I did the %@ so that this will automatically determine which object in the array was tapped, rather than manually putting in a new method and button for each UIImageView (I may have to end up doing that). I'm getting errors regarding "array" and "deleteButtonPressed" (use of undeclared identifier), I can't for the life of me figure out what to put instead. I'm still learning the basics and how inheritance in this language works. Any help or advice would be great! I should probably post the whole view controller file to show the related inheritance:

```
 - (IBAction)grabImage {
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
        [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.imageView.bounds inView:self.imageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    } 

    else {
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
    }
    [self.imgPicker resignFirstResponder];
}
// Sets the image in the UIImageView
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    if (imageView.image == nil) {
        imageView.image = img;
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;

    }

    if (imageView2.image == nil) {
        imageView2.image = img;
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }
    if (imageView3.image == nil) {
        imageView3.image = img;
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    self.user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray* array = [[self.user objectForKey:@"images"]mutableCopy];
    while(array == nil)
    {
        [self.user setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@""] forKey:@"images"];
        array = [[self.user objectForKey:@"images"]mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"%@",@"attempting to create an array to store the images in");
    }

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    NSLog(@"Image on didenterbackground: %@", imageView);
    NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)]];

    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView2.image)]];
     [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView3.image)]];

            [self.user setObject:array forKey:@"images"];
    [user synchronize];

            }

- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        self.user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSLog(@"It is %@", self.user);
        NSMutableArray* array = [[self.user objectForKey:@"images"]mutableCopy];
        imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
        imageView2.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
        imageView3.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:2]];


        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                                   object:app];

        backToGalleryButton.hidden = YES;
        tapToDeleteLabel.hidden = YES;
        deleteButton1.hidden = YES;
        [super viewDidLoad];

    }

     - (IBAction)deleteButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *deleteAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                                              message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this photo?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
    [deleteAlertView show];

}

- (void)deleteAlertView:(UIAlertView *)deleteButtonPressed
       didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != [deleteButtonPressed cancelButtonIndex]) {
        [array removeObject:@"%@", deleteButtonPressed];
    }       

}
```

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code, but to help us out can you post the actual error as posted in the console?

Comment: Yes sir, the only error is "Use of undeclared identifier `array`." Just as a side note, what else is wrong with my code? (Outside of not using a tableview)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue here is `[array removeObject:@"%@", deleteButtonPressed];`

Yes, that is one of the issues (even ignoring the invalid syntax).  The array does not contain your `UIAlertView`, it contains whatever objects `[user objectForKey:@"images"]` contains.  Which seem like they should be `NSData` instances and which in any case are definitely not your `UIAlertView` instance(s).

So in other words, you can't pass the `UIAlertView` to the array in order to have the array magically work out what item the `UIAlertView` is supposed to correspond to.  Instead what you should do is tag the `UIAlertView` with the index it corresponds to when you create it.  You can do this like:

```
UIAlertView *deleteAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                                              message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this photo?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
int imageIndex = <figure out the index of the associated array element based upon 'sender'>;
deleteAlertView.tag = imageIndex;
```

...and then when the button is pressed, you do:

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:deleteButtonPressed.tag];
```

And to fix up that "undeclared identifier" issue, you should declare `array` in your header and not in `viewDidLoad`.  You want it to be a private instance variable, not a local variable.

Also note that deleting an element from `[[user objectForKey:@"images"] mutableCopy]` will *not* automatically cause the corresponding element to be deleted from `[user objectForKey:@"images"]`.  You need to write the modified array back to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` if you want the modification to actually persist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, I will get to work on everything right now. Also, I was wondering how I would write the modified array back to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, and would I do this in my `deleteAlertView method? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You would do it after you are finished modifying the array, so yes, `deleteAlertView` would be a reasonable place.  You can do it like `[self.user setObject:array forKey:@"images"]`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again for all of your help and taking the time to explain it, I appreciate it!

Comment: Also, to figure out the index of the associated array element based upon sender, would that look like: `int imageIndex = [[deleteButtonPressed] sender];`? Sorry for so many novice questions, the Objective-C book I read doesn't cover any of this, looks like I need to go buy a more in-depth one.

Comment: No, it would not look like that.  How it looks will depend upon how you are setting up the button(s) that call(s) `deleteButtonPressed`.  I assume you have done this in XCode's Interface Builder?  If so then you can assign each button the appropriate tag in Interface Builder, and then the code might look like `imageIndex = sender.tag;`.

Answer (score 2):

There is one thing wring here, but first a relatively minor point:

```
 - (void)deleteAlertView:(UIAlertView *)deleteButtonPressed didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

the phrase "deleteButtonPressed" implies an even, as it ends in a verb. It Is actually referring to an object, specifically a parameter of the type UIAlertView. you should call it something more like AlertView.

Secondly this line is quite wrong:

```
[array removeObject:@"%@", deleteButtonPressed];
```

You are trying to remove a string. If that method accepted an argument list (where you pass multiple objects separated by a comma), you would be removing literally "deleteButtonPressed". You want to remove the object that is being pointed to by the deleteButtonPressed variable. So all you have to do is:

```
 [array removeObject:deleteButtonPressed];
```

Comment: Yes, except `deleteButtonPressed` is not actually in the array to begin with.  What the OP really wants to do is remove the array element that *corresponds to* `deleteButtonPressed`.

Comment: Completely missed the long code section (I'm on my phone if that's any excuse :))  I'm going through it now and will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error "Use of undeclared identifier array" because you declare the array in different methods, but not in your deleteAlertView method. I suggest reading up on variable scope.

Fixing that, however, will not get your code to work because you have some fundamental design flaws that need to be worked out.

You mention that you are a beginner, so I would suggest reading through and completing several beginner tutorials before attempting this app. I know it is fun to dive right into a project, but you will very likely get frustrated and also develop bad habits with respect to app design/engineering. In particular, I would try to get a firmer understand of variable scope and MVC design patterns.

Comment: Could whomever down voted please leave a brief explanation of why?

Comment: I would guess that you were downvoted because you're addressing the root issue rather than "answering the question". /me rolls eyes

Comment: @sosborn I up-voted your answer, I'm not sure why anyone would down-vote it as your suggestions were pretty helpful to me.

Comment: I just like to have feedback on downvotes because if the feedback is constructive I can improve my future answers.